# Why Groups inside Salesforce Org are not showing in Community?

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, partner-communities

As the title suggest, I've created several groups inside Saleforce but when I add a Navigational Item of Object Groups doesn't show any record.

I have followed these [instruction](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_designer_add_groups_to_communities.htm&type=5) but nothing happens,

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups in Salesforce are separated and not sharable to be a group in Communities. You must create a group in Communities for it to show up in Communities.

There is already an idea posting about this: 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwkzAAA

Comment: This is a really confusing piece of design by Salesforce to make the Communities Groups not visible in SF or vice versa.

Comment: Yep agreed, but unfortunately they built it this way, and to be quite honest this won't change for a while lol.....

Answer (score 0):

You have  to switch to classic mode to view the Group object and create Group record.
click on the profile and then switch to classic mode.